# MySQL: Foreign key constraints that exceed max depth

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, sql-delete, cascading-deletes

I have `MySQL Server 5.1.62` installed on production server. I am monitoring mysql server's error log file every day and suddenly I found below error in my error log file.

> InnoDB: Cannot delete/update rows with cascading foreign key constraints that exceed max depth of 250
>       Please drop excessive foreign constraints and try again

I have a database structure with **primary key - foreign key** relationships with proper update/delete actions and I need to delete data of child tables if the data in parent table deleted by application or manually (backend).

I had googled this issue but I can't find proper solution. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you post your schema? I suspect you have a loop in your foreign key constraints. You don't have to post the entire tables, just the columns that are mentioned in foreign key settings.

Comment: I agree with @Barmar here. Your db schema might have a circular foreign key constraint causing the error on delete. We need to see the table+column schema to be more helpful.

Comment: What changed right before you started seeing this error message?

Comment: Deleting multiple rows from tbl_indentmaster and because of cascade delete data from all child tables were deleted so I found this error

Comment: I don't mean that kind of change. What changed in the db schema or in the server configuration just before you started seeing this error message?

Comment: No, haven't done any changes. Deleteing some old data which were not in use

Comment: It's really hard to figure it out from the diagram, text would be better. All we need are the table names and the `references` clauses.

Comment: In my schema design all the relationship created with cascade delete.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a recursive constraint related to `tbl_indentmaster` in your diagram. What's the query you are trying to run?

Comment: I am using simple delete query. **DELETE FROM tbl_indentmaster WHERE indentId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,...,150,151,155,156,....)**.

Comment: @SaharshShah Do you get the same error if you delete just _one_ `indentId`?

Comment: No, It will run for small amount of data. But it gives error if I want to delete more data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the original answers by @Devart and @Catcall here but I'd like to add a few things after exchanging a few comments with the OP.

First, I have reduced the schema image representation to only the tables that are affected by a `DELETE` query on `tbl_indentmaster`.

From what I could see there are *no* circular FK references in this schema diagram.

Also, the OP ran the following query:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_indentmaster WHERE indentId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,...,150,151,155,156,....)
```

That's an aweful lot of rows to delete. On enquiring further the OP claims that the query works for smaller subsets of `indentId`'s.

From this I think we can take two possibilities:

1. There's a bug in MySQL (highly unlikely but possible) which causes large queries with `CASCADE DELETE` like yours to fail. Note I am suggesting the possibility of a *new* bug *not* the one [posted already][2]. Ideally the number of rows to delete should *not* matter.
2. There is a particular `indentId` entry within `tbl_indentmaster` which is causing the entire query to fail.

I'd suggest that you first try to diagnose the issue considering point (2) is the actual culprit. You can break the `DELETE` query into smaller chunks and find the offending id's.

If this script is something that has to be periodically executed through code (in a larger application) then you should consider executing the query in smaller chunks there as well (probably 15 id's per query is a good start IMO). In addition to doing this I'd suggest logging errors with offending id's in a log file so you know exactly which entries are failing.

Comment: I have already grouped sata in small chunks and deleted it. I want to fing root cause of this error. I also think this is limitation of mysql.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this link - [Cascade Delete results in "Got error -1 from storage engine"](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=57255). There is a suggestion.

Also, as a solution you may try to do it without *ON DELETE CASCADE* option, just use [DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html) statement that removes records from some tables (*multiple-table syntax*).

Comment: I had already used ON DELETE CASCADE and I am getting the error when I execute DELETE Query. This is not the solution of my question

Comment: exceeding is when you have too much ... this can't be solved by adding more

Comment: I had checked that link but not find exact solution for this situation

Answer (score 3):

The picture of a schema isn't very useful, because it doesn't show any cascading declarations. For example, if deletes are supposed to cascade from tbl_indentmaster to tbl_tepdetails, but deletes are *not* supposed to cascade from tbl_tepdetails to tbl_tepnoting, then then I'd expect some deletes to fail. (But with a different error message.)

If there *is* a circular referential constraint that's causing this, I'd expect it to be caused in part by a cascading reference from tbl_indentmaster to tbl_tepdetails. You might want to try dropping that foreign key constraint for testing. Do that on a tset sserver, not on the production server.

If this started suddenly, and your database worked correctly before, I'd first think about

- restoring the database from backup, or
- restoring the schema from backup, and reloading the current data, or
- checking out the current version and rebuilding the database. (You do have the [database schema under version control](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/02/get-your-database-under-version-control.html), don't you?)

I'll assume you don't have a good backup, and that you don't have your schema under version control.

Are you starting with a good database? Run [mysqlcheck](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlcheck.html).  Read that documentation carefully. Don't `--repair` before you have a tested, good backup.

Assuming that your database is good, that cascading deletes *ought* to work correctly in your database, and that your Google skills are good, I think your best *start* is to

- install MySQL 5.5 or 5.6 on a test server,
- load your database onto that test server, and
- see whether you can reproduce that specific error.

To load your database onto the test server, dump the contents using [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html). Don't copy files at the filesystem level--one or more of them might be corrupt.

Although this *might* not resolve your issue, it *might* tell you exactly where the issue is. If it works correctly, you know the problem is probably related to the server version, and that it might be resolved with a version upgrade.

Comment: I have updated mysql version to 5.5 but still I am facing the same issue

Comment: In my schema design all the relationship created with cascade delete. And till mow i am not deleting any rows from db but now i want to delete past data so i got this error

Comment: Did you drop the foreign key constraint between tbl_indentmaster and tbl_tepdetails on a test server, then try to delete rows from tbl_indentmaster?

Comment: It will work if i remove constraint from db. But i can't do that. As per my understanding the error occurs because of exceed depth of constraint as if i delete 50 rows from indentmaster table it automatically deletes more than 1000 rows from different tables so it crosses the depth of cascade delete

Comment: Your understanding is wrong; the number of rows is irrelevant. The problem is *probably* related to the number of tables you're cascading the delete to. And that's *probably* because you have a circular reference. (The delete cascades back to the table it started in.) If it works when you drop the FK constraint between tbl_indentmaster and tbl_tepdetails, put *that* constraint back, and drop the FK constraint between tbl_tepdetails and tbl_tepmapbidder. Repeat until you isolate the problem, which I expect will be a circular FK reference.